# Envio de email com template no Django

Tags: django, envio-de-email, django-templates, django-rest-framework

Estou tentando enviar um template por email no Django, porém ele não renderiza, já tentei diversas forma e todas elas dá o mesmo erro, o render_to_string retorna o caminho do arquivo ('templates/email/confirma_cadastro.html').

```
def post(self, request):
    try:
      serializer = CadastroUsuarioSerializer(data=request.data)
      serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
      password = request.data.get('password')
      emailUser = request.data.get('email')
      nameUser = request.data.get('nome')
      user = serializer.save()
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save()

      template = render_to_string('templates/email/confirma_cadastro.html',
                                  {'nameUser': nameUser}, {'emailUser', emailUser}),

      email = EmailMessage(
          'Confirmação de cadastro',
          template,
          settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
          [emailUser],
      )
      email.fail_silently = False
      email.send()

      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except Exception as e:
      return Response(str(e.args[0]), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Somente quando coloco o 'template' que o envio não funciona, já fiz testes e substituindo o 'template' na variavel 'email' por um texto no lugar o e-mail é enviado normalmente.

configuração no settings.py

```
# CONFIG EMAIL
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 20000
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.intranet.********.sp.gov.br'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******@********.sp.gov.br'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '"Sistema de Cadastro"<sistemadecadastro@*********.sp.gov.br>'
```

Comment: Mostra como esta está a configurado para que o Dj intérprete qual servidor de e-mail usar quando for utilizado o envio

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com as informações solicitadas, acredito que o sistema de envio esteja funcionando, pois substituindo o template por texto o e-mail é enviado. O problema é que ele não consegue puxar o template, o caminho do template tbm está certo, pois mesmo colocando o arquivo HTML na mesma raiz da 'view.py' ele nao funciona

Comment: Talvez você esteja usando chaves únicas nas variáveis do template, e estas precisam ser chaves duplas `{{ como isso }}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language. Você poderia compartilhar uma parte do seu template de email também?